# Firebase REST API - Remove the First Item Added When Object's Property Count Reaches a Certain Size

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase object called `recent_notifications` that looks like:

```
recent_notifications: {
    12-24-2016 4:23:45 PM: {
        message: 'melody'       
    },
    12-24-2016 4:23:47 PM: {
        message: 'melody'       
    },
    12-25-2016 4:23:47 PM: {
        message: 'melody'       
    },
    .............
}
```

I would like to keep only the last 50 properties (notifications) of the object since this object correlates directly to a view in my app.  If I was using the JavaScript library, I could do it with the following:

```
queueRef.startAt().limit(1).on("child_added", function(){
    // Determine the number of properties in recent_notifications and 
    // remove the oldest one if the count reaches a certain threshold 
});
```

How would I do the same thing using the REST endpoints?

Comment: You can use the REST Streaming API to get similar behavior to `child_added`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What's the longest I can keep a connection alive using streaming?  And if a connection does go down, does it automatically reconnect or will I need to catch those situations myself?  Also, the link you pointed to only mentions streaming from Firebase -> my server.  Can I achieve writes to Firebase by opening a stream from my server -> Firebase?

Comment: Given that there is no client-side code of Firebase when you use REST streaming, you will have to handle reconnects in your own client-side code. You'd handle writes through the regular REST endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way in the REST API to do this at the moment.  I ended up making a GET request for the Firebase object in question and then running a filter over the response to get the oldest recent notification.  Once I got the oldest notification, I make a DELETE request to its Firebase URL to remove it.